# How to find Rth for the Thevenin Equivalent Circuit?

Tags: passive-networks, thevenin

[image: This is the circuit]

So we were given this circuit to solve for I1, I2, I3, and lastly the Thevenin Equivalent Circuit. I was able to solve for I1, I2, I3. However I am having a hard time computing the RTH at ab.

Here is the circuit I was trying to use to find RTH.
[image: RTH]

Comment: OK, what's the issue with the Rth that you were trying? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I can't figure out how to solve it since there is short curcuit at the left side.

Comment: That's not a "short circuit", it's just a connection between the top and bottom nodes.

Comment: Then how will I solve that?

Comment: Perhaps redraw the circuit in a more familiar way.

Comment: Think about @Tyler's suggestion.  What do you know about components that have the same voltage across them (because they are connected)?

Comment: Remember that, in order to find the equivalent impedance between two nodes, you must turn off all the independent sources and then you must place between the two nodes a test voltage generator. The ratio between the test voltage generator and the current flowing through it gives you the equivalent impedance. If you put a test voltage generator, you immediately see that no short circuit is present...

Comment: So how to find Rth?

Comment: Is it [(6+j20)||(4-j10)] ???